# Query producing undesired result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is my table:

[image]

I wrote the below query

```
select a.name as 'Roll up', 
        b.name as 'Appeal Category', 
        C.NAME as 'Planned Appeal', 
        D.NAME as 'PME' 
from GROUP_TABLE A 
left outer JOIN GROUP_TABLE B ON A.MKTPLANID = B.MKTPLANID AND A.PARENTID = B.PMKID 
left outer JOIN GROUP_TABLE C ON A.MKTPLANID = C.MKTPLANID AND B.PARENTID = C.PMKID 
left outer JOIN GROUP_TABLE D ON A.MKTPLANID = D.MKTPLANID AND C.PARENTID = D.PMKID 
where a. caption = 'Roll up'
```

Below is the output for my query:

[image]

Along with this result, I also wan to show up the Parent ID of the caption 'PME' alone. So I want one more column as PME ID showing IDs '04' and '07'

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: wouldnt that just be `D.ParentID as [PME ID]`?

Comment: Doing so is showing up the ParentIDs of caption 'Roll up' that is '01' and '08' are pulled

Comment: @Akansha That would happen with `A.ParentID`, not `D.ParentID`

Comment: could you show the complete query you used to get the output, looks like theMKTPLANID and PMKID columns are missing from the select

Comment: oops..sorry about that. The output is on a excel sheet. So the screen shot resembles it. But on my real query (the one above) I have not selected any ID

Comment: What is the relationship between the PME rows and the Roll up rows?

Comment: A PME belongs to a RollUp. So They have same MKTPLANID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you have given

@JamieD77 is correct that the only possible answer is to add D.ParentID to the select statement

This is because of the last outer join

```
left outer JOIN GROUP_TABLE D ON A.MKTPLANID = D.MKTPLANID AND C.PARENTID = D.PMKID
```

Table C in this case are the 2 rows with the Planned Appeal as the Caption.

They link to the Rows with PME as the caption where they share the same `MKTPLANID` and where the Planned Appeal `PARENTID` equals the PME `PMKID`.

Therefore the rows in Table D will be the 2 rows with a `Caption` of PME, the `PARENTID` of the 2 rows is 04 and 07.

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should create views as your pre-results and then you can apply further operations on it, or you can write this query as nested query style. there are dependencies of one result to other. so its execution strategy does not work properly. you can write this command to check execution strategy.                SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON